# multiple upload images on c#/jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

is there out there any multiple upload images easy to users to upload images like the activex file uploader on facebook.

but free :)

i update my questions i saw that everyone recommend about the flash uploader.
i have the problem that i"m using sessions,
i"m passing the user album id for relation to the image that  been uploaded
and the user id that uploded the image

this is the code in the first page

```
  <div id="divUploadImage" style="display: none;">
                    <FlashUpload:FlashUpload ID="flashUpload" runat="server" UploadPage="Upload2.axd"
                        OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete()" FileTypeDescription="Images" FileTypes="*.gif; *.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg"
                        UploadFileSizeLimit="3000000" TotalUploadSizeLimit="40000000" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
```

and the code after upload fire on the second page

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

  for (int j = 0; j < context.Request.Files.Count; j++)
                {

 HttpPostedFile uploadFile = context.Request.Files[j];
  SaveImages(uploadFile, "", albumid,out returnPhotoId); // my function to save ,albumId is the session
                 }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Where does your SaveImages file save the Images? Uploadify takes care of moving all the files to the directory you specify. Are you just moving them afterwards. If so you can just use my .ashx example to save to the proper location the first time. We are using this uploader to upload files for multiple users all at once and the files are saved in each users folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It uses flash as well, and I highly recommend it. It is a highly customizeable and free product.

**For posting to another page after uploading all files:**

Make 3 hidden fields like so:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_UserID" name="hdf_UserID"  />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_AlbumID" name="hdf_AlbumID" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_ImageFiles" name="hdf_ImageFiles" />
```

and here is how you set up your button to post to the second page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Submit" PostBackUrl="YourPage.aspx" />
```

Once on the second page you can grab the information out of the request like so:

```
Request["hdf_UserID"].ToString()
Request["hdf_AlbumID"].ToString()
Request["hdf_ImageFiles"].ToString()
```

you can store all the files in the hidden field and I would recommend | delimited
then you can just do a .split on the other page

**For the .ahx page of the uploadify uploader:**

using the scriptData option you can pass information to the second page.

```
 var auth = "<% = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value %>"
 var user = $('[id$=hdf_UserID]').val();
 var album = $('[id$=hdf_AlbumID]').val();

 $('[id$=fileInput]').uploadify({
        'uploader': '../Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '../Uploadify/Upload2.ashx',
        'scriptData': {'Token': auth, 'User': user, 'Album': album},
```

in the .ashx of uploadify you can get the scriptData by the following:

```
string user = context.Request["User"];
string album = context.Request["Album"];
```

This code is uploadify specific but hopefully it will help you understand yours

Comment: i"m using sessions and this my problem to using that, you have any solution?

Comment: what specifically are you using the sessions for?

Comment: i"m passing the userId, and albumId

Comment: If you are passing the userId and the albumId to next page why dont you store all information sent to the next page in hidden fields. Then when you post to the next page you can grab the information out of the Request like so: Request["userId"].ToString()

Comment: i didn't accully understand how can i grab hidden fields from the first page by the request

Comment: If you are posting the information to the next page, you can grab all controls from the previous page through the request.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the information to a file used by the uploader or to the next page after uploading all the files?

Comment: to the file used by the uploader

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It is done with Flash. There are a plenty of solutions on the internet. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx) is one from codeproject.

Answer (score 1):

I used the library located at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx for my project.  It's pretty lightweight and lends itself well to modification.

Basically, it's a multi-file uploader written in Flex.  It's straightforward enough that you can also bust open the code and make changes if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) with ASP.NET MVC to create a multi-file upload script with automatic image previews all inline with AJAX. One thing to keep in mind if you use Session variables in your upload action being hit by SWFUpload/Uploadify is that Flash gets its own SessionID and anything placed in the Session after a Flash upload request is placed in the *Flash* Session.

Comment: this is my problem actually , i'm using sessions 
you have any solution for this?

Comment: @avnic: It depends on *why* you're using the session.  There is no way to have flash pick up your pre-existing session.  One example of a workaround could be by storing your images in a folder associated with the userid, then check that folder from your main session.  The workaround is really dependent on your implementation.

Comment: I agree! We really need more information as to your implementation in order to best answer this question. There are several options available to you, but the best one can only be given when we understand the whole scope of the project.

Comment: The solution I came up with was pretty hacky. I wrote a custom Session implementation that optionally accepts a SessionID as a parameter in order to modify another user's Session. The code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262054/asp-net-mvc-alternative-to-using-session/1262422#1262422 isn't quite the most recent iteration, but the only changes I've made is to the Add/Remove methods. I can't guarantee the quality of that code, but I can tell you that it does work in all my tests.