# Upload file jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

Can anyone please recomend one?

I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Thank you

Comment: I also need to create a thumbnail. Can I do it before the image is saved to the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [uploadify.](http://www.uploadify.com/) It uses flash as well but I highly recommend it. I have used in several locations and it has always fit my need. It is also highly customizeable so that is always a plus. It is also free so you really cant beat it.

You can also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322269/multiple-upload-images-on-c-jquery/1322298#1322298)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.uploadify.com/demo/

Comment: Does flash bring any downside? In this page http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/, the author says IE doesn't pass cookies properly. Is this true?

Comment: That is true but there are plenty of ways around it. Check out the question I referred to. The person there was dealing with the same problem but I stated several solutions that will work there. He was able to get one of the solution working in his case. I dont think using flash should be a con. It should fulfill all of your needs.