# facebook photo upload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple upload images on c#/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322269/multiple-upload-images-on-c-jquery)

hey guys!

Yesterday i made here a question about an input type="file" to select multiple files instead of one. And you gave me some solutions like plupload and SWFUpload and some more.

But if possible i want to try something a little bit different, like facebook. The solution that you offered me yesterday have flash, or silverlight, html5, gears or browserplus...

So if you could show me an example like the photo upload of facebook or another i would be very happy!

Regards!

Comment: I don't understand? Facebook uses Flash too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: [Multiple Upload images with c#/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322269/multiple-upload-images-on-c-jquery)?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's uploader **is** a Flash uploader. View the source.

Comment: Sorry i didnt knew that.. but can you give me a solution that uses C# asp.net and/or AJAX?

Comment: Do you know what AJAX means? ASP.NET and AJAX are not competing technologies, they're complimentary ones. AJAX generally relies on the server-side component that ASP.NET (or PHP, or Ruby on Rails, or any number of other frameworks) provides. Flash uploaders don't need AJAX to work, and they'll do just fine with ASP.NET.

Comment: sorry if i didnt born an expert like you geek! As far as i know STACKOVERFLOW is a website where people (geeks and beginners) ask their doubts and concerns about a problem.Learn with your mistakes!

Comment: That's fine, but don't throw terms out as requirements if you don't know what they actually mean. Your requirements aren't "ASP.NET and/or AJAX", they're "allow multiple-file uploads like Facebook does on my ASP.NET website".